# Add attribute to custom fields in Django

Tags: django, attributes, field

I'll be as brief as possible.

I want to able to do this

```
{{ video.youtube_url.video_id }}
```

by implementing something like the following custom field:

```
class YouTubeURLField(URLField):
    description = _("YouTubeURL")

    def _video_id(self):
      return re.search('(?<=\?v\=)[\w-]+', self.value)
    video_id = property(_video_id)

    def __init__(self, verbose_name=None, name=None, verify_exists=True, **kwargs):
      super(YouTubeURLField, self).__init__(**kwargs)
      kwargs['max_length'] = kwargs.get('max_length', 200)
      CharField.__init__(self, verbose_name, name, **kwargs)
      self.validators.append(YouTubeURLValidator(verify_exists=verify_exists))
```

This:

```
    def _video_id(self):
      return re.search('(?<=\?v\=)[\w-]+', self.value)
    video_id = property(_video_id)
```

Does not sucessfully add a "video_id" attribute to my custom YouTubeURLField.

Everything else works flawlessly.

I understand there maybe better design considerations in terms of the YouTube custom field, but I'd rather just understand, first, why this doesn't work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I wanted to do it this way, because it seems it makes more sense from a design stand point.  The video id is an attribute of the YouTube URL and not of the model itself.

I figured it out.  I overrode the to_python function to return a YouTubeURL object.

```
class YouTubeURL(object):
  def __init__(self, value):
    self.value = value

  @property
  def video_id(self):
    regex = re.compile(r'/v/([A-Za-z0-9\-_]+)', re.IGNORECASE)

    id = regex.search(self.value)
    return id.group(1)

  def __unicode__(self):
    return "%s" % (self.value,)

  def __str__(self):
    return "%s" % (self.value,)

  def __len__(self):
    return len(self.value)

class YouTubeURLField(URLField):
    description = _("YouTubeURL")

    __metaclass__ = SubfieldBase

    def to_python(self, value):
      return YouTubeURL(value)

    def __init__(self, verbose_name=None, name=None, verify_exists=True, **kwargs):
      super(YouTubeURLField, self).__init__(**kwargs)
      kwargs['max_length'] = kwargs.get('max_length', 200)
      CharField.__init__(self, verbose_name, name, **kwargs)
      self.validators.append(YouTubeURLValidator(verify_exists=verify_exists))
```

Answer (score 2):

Django fields are [descriptors](http://users.rcn.com/python/download/Descriptor.htm), which means that accessing them does not return the field, but rather the field value. You will need to [override the Django field methods](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-model-fields/) in order to return an object that has the attributes you care about, as well as a sanely-defined `__unicode__()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you can't have it as a property of the model?

In order to access data from an object not directly contained within the fields I frequently implement a pattern along the lines of:

```
class: Sheep(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    @property
    def sheep_says(self):
        return "Baa... my name is %s ... baa" % self.name
```

Which you would then access in the template with:

```
{{ sheep.sheep_says }}
```